# Storing data to a file within a programme

Tags: python

PYTHON
I am making a quiz and at the start I ask for the user to input a username. I want to be able to store the username and a high score that they get or the highest point. But i dont know how to store the username or to save every single one that has been submitted
Please help and be clear. Appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You need to user a database.  ``anydbm`` is embedded in python and a good start for very simple programs.

Comment: @HackinGuy sorry im a bit new to python but thanks ill try it out

Comment: ur welcome, here is more [info](https://docs.python.org/2/library/anydbm.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON` to store the user information.
This is an example of what you may use.

```
import json
import os

DB_NAME = "db.json"

if not os.path.isfile(DB_NAME):
    with open(DB_NAME, "w") as f:
        json.dump({},f)

def get_db():
    with open(DB_NAME) af f:
        return json.load(f)

def write_db(db_dict):
    with open(DB_NAME,'w') af f:
        json.dump(f,indent=4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = raw_input("Username: ")
    highscore = int(raw_input("High-score: "))
    write_db(get_db()[username] = highscore)
```

This is the `JSON` documentation: [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)
To understand `JSON` better read this: [link](http://pythontips.com/2013/08/08/storing-and-loading-data-with-json/)